# Vue.js - Load a component from a url on-demand and inject it in your app

Tags: vue.js

I will like to from a Vue app load a component from a URL(could be in the same domain or not),  create an instance of it, and show it on the current view.
The idea is to have a component storage service that will contain lots of components, and load them on-demand from the app, depending on the need.
I will like to avoid having all the components included directly on the app.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent article exactly for this usecase - https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/

Comment: Thanks for the article. Actually, I've already read this. I was looking for a more built-in way of doing it. The proposed way of this article is ok but requires too much boilerplate outside the Vue.js ecosystem.

Comment: I was not aware that you've read the article. I know of no other way to accomplish your goal. Vue.js ecosystem mostly relies on bundling the components of your app together at the same time.

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyway.  :-)